# Prove the following inequality $6 \cdot 3^\frac18-5 > 3^{\frac14}$

Tags: inequality, quadratics, radicals, factoring, number-comparison

So I had this homework to do in which I had to prove that:

$$6 \cdot 3^\frac18-5 > 3^{\frac14}$$
Any ideas ?

Comment: What did you try doing?

Comment: Raise each side to the power of $4$. Since both sides are positive, the direction of the inequality will be preserved.

Comment: @barakmanos then you have to prove that $(6 \cdot 3^\frac18-5)^4 > 3$ but why is it easier? I have it written on paper in front of me and can't see why it helps..?

Answer (score 3):

It's a quadratic inequality of $\sqrt[8]3$.

Id est, we have $\left(\sqrt[8]3-1\right)\left(\sqrt[8]3-5\right)<0$, which is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=3^{\frac18}$, observe that $1<x<5$

As $$\left(x-5\right)\left(x-1\right)<0$$
$$x^2-6x+5<0$$
$$x^2<6x-5$$

Sub $x=3^{\frac18}$.